# Angular2 - updating variable after function (promise?)

Tags: asynchronous, promise, wait, angular

I havea some problem. In my registration I want to view error message if user already exists in the database. So I created "serverAnswer" variable which will handle the error answer from server.

My register.service.ts content

```
@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  public serverAnswer: Object;

  getAnswer() {
    return this.serverAnswer;
  }

  addUser(user: User) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post('/users/register', JSON.stringify(user), {headers: headers})
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.json().success) {
          window.location.href = "/";
        }
        if(response.json().error) {
          this.serverAnswer = response.json();
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, at the start the "serverAnswer" variable is empty. The "response.json().error" handle my error text. Okay, now it's time to show my register.component.ts content.

```
export class RegisterComponent {
  constructor(private http: Http, private registerService: RegisterService) {}

  serverAnswer: Object;

  onSubmit(userName: string, userPassword: string, userEmail: string) {
    this.registerService.addUser(new User(userName, userPassword, userEmail))
    this.serverAnswer = this.registerService.getAnswer();
  }
}
```

The problem is that the "systemAnswer" from RegisterService has been updated BEFORE the function addUser was done. The result is that if this user already exists in the database, then for the first time the "systemAnswer" is empty and for the second time is handling the response.json().error text.

This place:

```
this.registerService.addUser(new User(userName, userPassword, userEmail))
this.serverAnswer = this.registerService.getAnswer();
```

What should I do to update the serverAnswer variable only when the addUser function is done?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you return Observable object from your service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RegisterService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  addUser(user: User) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');

    return this.http.post('/users/register', JSON.stringify(user), {headers: headers})
        .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

and then use it in controller:

```
export class RegisterComponent {
    constructor(private http: Http, private registerService: RegisterService) {}

    serverAnswer: Object;

    onSubmit(userName: string, userPassword: string, userEmail: string) {
        this.registerService.addUser(new User(userName, userPassword, userEmail))
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    if (response.success) {
                        window.location.href = "/";
                    } else if (response.error) {
                        this.serverAnswer = response;
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I have a problem `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.` I guess I should import some rxjs module?

Comment: you need to subscribe in controller I think, I updated the answer.

Comment: Now subscribe works but `TypeError: this.http.post(...).map is not a function`

Comment: Okay, I have imported import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; and works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Note that the final release of Angular 2 will use ES observables which do not have a `.map` method. You have been warned.